# PHP Array with each if

Tags: php

I want to create an array with values which can be added in order, but can be different number of vars used each time the file is posted, basically I have few if statements like this:

```
if(isset($file01)){
   $f01 = $file01;
 }
if(isset($file02)){
   $f02 = $file02;
 }
```

Then I have something like this:

```
$array = [$f01,$f02,$f03,$f04,$f05,$f06,];
```

I want to make the array unlimited, how can i do it with a loop (or maybe a switch?, to make each var be added to the array... the vars are files uploaded in order from file 01 to file 10...

Comment: There is an easier way of doing this. Have a look at the php manual for some ideas http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Why are you not directly adding values to the array in the if blocks?

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot really help, since it is unclear what you are actually trying to do. Your code snippet smells of fundamental miss understandings of how to process given data. But without you actually telling us what you want to do instead of how you _think_ you might be able to do it there is little we can say...

Comment: It's very simple, I have a mail script to add files and the array should be with the files from it... but i want it to be dynamic instead of given files

Comment: _"but i want it to be dynamic instead of given files"_ - and by that you mean what exactly again? Do you want the script to automatically read the files contained in a specific folder on the server? Then go research _that_, you should be able to find plenty on it.

Comment: I just need the array loop

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can refer to variables by their names AND construct those names dynamically.
The solution to your problem could look like this:

```
<?php

$file1 = 'test1';
$file2 = 'test2';
$file3 = 'test3';

$fileNames = [
    // old variable name => new variable name
    'file1' => 'f1',
    'file2' => 'f2',
    'file3' => 'f3'
];

foreach($fileNames as $oldVariableName=> $newVariableName) {
    if (isset(${$oldVariableName})) {
        ${$newVariableName} = ${$oldVariableName};
    }
}

echo $f1, PHP_EOL;
echo $f2, PHP_EOL;
echo $f3, PHP_EOL;
```

You could use a "for" loop of course, thus making it a more dynamic solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array();
if(isset($file01)){
  $f01 = $file01;
  $array[] = $f01;
}
if(isset($file02)){
  $f02 = $file02;
  $array[] = $f02;
}
```